# Can I use the task parallel library in a .Net 3.5 project?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I heard that the Task Parallel Library can be used in a .Net 3.5 project. Is this correct, and if yes, how do I use it? In .Net 4.0, it resides in System.Threading, but when I select .Net 3.5 as the target in Visual Studio 2010, I don't get access to classes like Parallel and the Parallel loops.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

(Legacy answer - it seems the backport for 3.5 is no longer readily available.)

You can't use the *full* Parallel Extensions, no...

... but if you install [Reactive Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29) for .NET 3.5, that [comes with a version of Parallel Extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322114720/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/11/19/9925951.aspx), so you can use that. I don't know how much of PFX is supported, but I suspect there's enough for most people. (There are some details in the blog post, but that was from 2009... I don't know about any changes in 2010 which may or may not have been backported.)

Note that this is unsupported, too - probably fine for hobby projects, but if I wanted to use PFX commercially, I'd upgrade to .NET 4.

Comment: If installing something else is a requirement, I think I'd install the .NET Framework 4 altogether.

Comment: @zneak: In some situations you may have the option of deploying another library, but not upgrading the framework version.

Comment: Works a charm, thank you! 
@zneak: I have .Net 4.0 installed, the problem is that I need to work with a component which can talk to .Net dlls, but up to .Net 3.5 only.

Comment: Most recent version with System.Threading.dll: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891787/threading-tasks-analog-in-rx-extensions-in-net-3-5/7747015#7747015

Comment: The version that targets 3.5 doesn't appear to be available any more.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Thanks, have edited the answer. I suspect there are ways of finding it, but most people would be better off spending their time moving off 3.5 :)

Answer (score 25):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, `Rx` backported `TPL` to `.NET 3.5`.

I have made a nuget (called **TaskParallelLibrary**) out of their `System.Threading.dll`, for easier integration.

You can get it from http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary.

Comment: It's Microsoft's module. I just repackaged it in nuget form. I don't have the source.