# "Compatibility Pack" for backporting new .NET Framework features?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, .net-2.0, compatibility

For various reasons I often find it desirable to write code that is compatible with .NET framework 2.0 or 3.5 or compatible with the .NET Compact Framework, but it is a problem that there are numerous "small" features in new .NET frameworks that are not available in the older frameworks or Compact Framework.

For example, I find extension methods are really useful, but the compiler depends on `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute` for this. You can easily define this attribute yourself and then use extension methods in .NET Framework 2.0 (under C# 3.0+). Likewise, it isn't too hard to manually define little .NET 4 types like `Tuple<T1,T2>` and `Lazy<T>`. By the way, if you want to use LINQ in .NET 2.0, you can use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).

Now suppose you make the `ExtensionAttribute` public so that other assemblies you write can use it. That's fine at first, but what if you then want to use a 3rd party library that also had the same idea? You add a reference to that library and now you've got a name collision. Oops.

I have also noticed that some new libraries are only available for .NET 4.0 or 3.5 even though they only have minor dependencies on it that could be resolved using a compatibility pack or LinqBridge.

It would sure be nice if there were "compatibility packs" for older .NET versions that defined these little features in a small DLL that you could justify including in projects of any size. Does such a thing exist?

**Update**: Judging by the silence, I guess there's no such thing. I might make such a OSS library myself if there is interest. So my new question is, what *smaller* features of .NET 4 (as opposed to monsters like WCF/WPF) would you miss if you were writing for .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NETCF or Silverlight? I'll start the list off...

- `ExtensionAttribute` (not in .NET 2)
- `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` delegates (not in .NET 2)
- LINQ-to-objects (not in .NET 2)
- `Tuple<...>` (not in .NET 3.5)
- `Lazy<T>` and `Lazy<T,TMetadata>` (not in .NET 3.5)
- Expression Trees (not in .NET 2; incomplete in .NET 3.5)
- Generics Variance (exists in .NET 2 but inaccessible from C# 3 and VB 9)
- `Reflection.Emit` (missing from .NETCF; not really a small feature but I miss it very much)

Comment: Related post - [Can I use the task parallel library in a .Net 3.5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2987439/465053)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theraot's Libraries**

You can use use `Theraot.Core` from [Theraot's Libraries](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot) to backport a great portion of .NET code to old versions starting with .NET 2.0 thanks to conditional compilation.

Out of the mentioned features, the following are included:

- `ExtensionAttribute`
- `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` delegates
- LINQ-to-objects
- `Tuple<...>`
- `Lazy<T>` and `Lazy<T,TMetadata>`
- Expression Tress

Also included are the following features not mentioned in the question:

- `HashSet<T>`
- `SortedSet<T>`
- `ThreadLocal<T>`
- `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`
- `BigInteger`
- `ConcurrentDictionary<Tkey, TValue>`
- etc...

Note: Support for `System.Threading.Tasks` is planned.

Sadly, there is only little documentation available at the moment of writing, yet any difference on behavior from the BCL can be considered a bug, and can be [reported via github](https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/issues).

Comment: I was able to compile [dotNetLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) for .Net 2.0 using Theraot's Libraries, and all their unit tests pass successfully (well, except for one - but that one fails even if I build for .net 4).  
Using [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) was not enough since it does not support expressions.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a "compatilibity pack", but since you mentioned [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx)... another "backported feature" I frequently use are the Parallel Extensions found (among other things) in the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) for Framework 3.5 SP1 (in `System.Threading.dll`). It includes full implementation of the Task Parallel Library and Parallel LINQ (PLINQ).

For .Net 4.0 there is the [Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) ([nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack)) from Microsoft.  Which provides many Async extention methods and provides support for the `async`/`await` keywords if using the C# 5 compiler.

Similarly for for .Net 3.5 there is the [AsyncBridge](http://nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35) that builds on the Reactive Extentions's TPL library to provide `async`/`await`.  There is also a version of AsyncBridge for .Net 4.0, but I am not sure why you would want that one over the one from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 3.5 you can use FSharp.Core.dll from the F# Runtime for .NET Framework 2.0.

> "The core library (FSharp.Core.dll) included in this redistributable package contains some APIs in the System namespaces that are identical to .NET Framework 4 APIs that are required for F# development."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829875%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

This includes `System.Tuple` et al. and `System.Lazy<T>`. (Not `Lazy<T,TMetadata>` though.) To use them just reference FSharp.Core.dll.

Edit: Turns out Lazy in `FSharp.Core.dll` is not a drop-in replacement, but more of an interop-class. It has the same properties but not the same constructors. Rather it's created e.g. like this:

```
Lazy<string> lazy = Microsoft.FSharp.Control.LazyExtensions.CreateFromValue("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful such a list will be, as it is potentially monstrous in size. The CLR is the same for 2.0, 3.0 & 3.5 so tehnically any of these post-2.0 features could make their way into a "compatibilty pack."

-Oisin