# Multithreading and ProgressBar

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Need to make an multithreading  application, which performs some activities and shows progress of **all work** in ProgressBar. Here is the code. Only thread named "thread - 0" makes all work. I need to distribute work between all threads.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const float maxWorkedValue = 10;
        const int threadsCount = 5;
        float totalProgress;
        int threadSleepTime = 1;

         object locker = new object();
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            prBar.Maximum =  (int)maxWorkedValue;
            prBar.Step = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
            {
                threads.Add(new Thread(BeginCalculate) { Name = "Thread - " + i.ToString() });
                threads[i].Start();
            }
        }




        void BeginCalculate()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < maxWorkedValue; i++)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    float currentProgress = CalculateLongTask(i);
                    Update((currentProgress / maxWorkedValue) * 100, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                    Thread.Sleep(threadSleepTime);
                }
            }
        }


        float CalculateLongTask(int value)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<value;i++)
                Thread.Sleep(threadSleepTime);

            return totalProgress++;
        }

        void Update(float i, string threadName)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new Action<float, string>(Update), new object[] { i, threadName });
                return;
            }
            label1.Text = threadName;
            prBar.Value = (int)i;
        }

    }
```

UPDATE2:
I've updated the code above. But it not resolved the problem. How to synchronize the variable "i" between different threads?  An exception (progressbar.Max) is thrown. Why?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < maxWorkedValue; i++)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                float currentProgress = CalculateLongTask(i);
                Update((currentProgress / maxWorkedValue) * 100, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not a solution, but why aren't you using a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) out of curiosity?

Comment: Correction: Thread 0 runs for a minute and then an exception (progressbar.Max) is thrown. Please post real code and/or include such details.

Comment: Re the Update: OK, so if you get that then what is the real problem? Are there resources to be locked? etc.

Comment: Re update2: `prBar.Maximum = maxWorkedValue * threadsCount;`

Comment: And consider where the real work is done, don't just Sleep() all over the place. That is very critical for what/when to lock.

Comment: Henk Holterman, it throws an error "Value of '60' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name: Value"

Comment: Just set that Maximum a lot higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

If I understood you correctly you want to execute a loop (i.e.`for (int i = 0; i < maxWorkedValue; i++)` ) concurrently among many threads.

This is extremely easier to accomplish using the **Parallel extensions
<sup>1</sup>**.

Here's your modified code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const float maxWorkedValue = 100;
    const int threadCount = 5;
    float maxWorkedValue2 = 1;

    Thread thread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        prBar.Maximum = (int)maxWorkedValue;
        prBar.Step = 1;

        thread = new Thread(BeginCalculate) { Name = "Father thread" };
        thread.Start();
    }

    void BeginCalculate()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, (int)maxWorkedValue,
            (i) =>
            {
                float currentProgress = CalculateLongTask(i);

                // here we are (probably) in a thread child 
                //of "Father thread" so let's use ManagedThreadId instead of the name...
                Update((currentProgress / maxWorkedValue) * 100, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(2);
                return;
            });
    }


    float CalculateLongTask(int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
            Thread.Sleep(15);

        return maxWorkedValue2++;
    }

    void Update(float i, string threadName)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action<float, string>(Update), new object[] { i, threadName });
            return;
        }
        label1.Text = threadName;
        prBar.Value = Math.Min((int)i, 100);
    }

}
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup>
If you're using .NET 4.0 Parallel extensions comes with the framework.
If you're using .NET 3.5, look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project) to know how to use it.

Comment: I have a task to make what I've described above.

Comment: It's good, but I have to make a task strictly. I have to use the class Thread to "performs some activities and shows progress of all work in ProgressBar". How many threads you use in your edit?

Comment: @Alex: parallel library calculates the best number of thread to use according CPU cores number. So it depends on your CPU...

Comment: 1. It doesn't work. The progress bar's value doesn't increase.   2.And how  can I do this using the class Thread and List<Thread> threads?

Comment: @Alex: you should avoid using `Thread` directly in most cases.

Comment: @Alex: it works, I tested id. You probably copied my first version of the code where I missed `thread.Start();` line ;). Anyway, if you strictly need to use `Thread` class (homework ?) you should specify it in the question...

Comment: @Alex: have a look at the example I've posted here --> http://0bj3ct1v3.pastebin.com/HAYcbhMG it should be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, your locking scheme is broken:

```
void BeginCalculate()  // main thread method
{
    lock (locker)
    {
       ....  // 1 thread at a time
    }
}
```

All threads are run in sequence, you're not really multi-threading.

I can't comment on the rest except to say it doesn't look like something you should use for real.

You should probably outline what you really need to do, It won't be Sleep().