# Threading.Tasks analog in Rx extensions in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, system.reactive

Is it possible to use Reactive Extensions (Rx) to create applications in .NET 3.5 that perform parallelization or is it limited in some way? I downloaded Rx from here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=26649 and after creating a simple project with referenced reactive assemblies, I failed to find any classes corresponding to Tasks in .NET 4.0. I'm trying to find classes for 'Task', but alas I can not find any. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [samples from the rx wiki](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc1) can help you.

The simplest background task would be:

```
var o = Observable.Start
(
    () => 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating..."); 
        Thread.Sleep(3000); 
        Console.WriteLine("Done."); 
    }
);

o.First();   // subscribe and wait for completion of background operation
```

But you may also want to look at the forkjoin examples.

Answer (score 5):

As some here mentioned, you can find a backported `System.Threading.dll` in an old `Rx` installation.

For an easier integration, I have made a nuget (called **TaskParallelLibrary**) out of it.

You can get it from http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, the last version of the Reactive Extensions to include "[the back ported standalone DLL named System.Threading.dll](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/11/19/9925951.aspx)" is [Reactive Extensions (Rx) v1.0.2856.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24940) released 2/11/2011 (in Rx_Net35.msi).

(I actually got it as Rx_Net35.v1.0.2856.0.msi, downloaded in May, I think from CodePlex; can't find that any more... it installed as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions\v1.0.2856.0\Net35\System.Threading.dll` on my 64-bit system.)

Comment: Check out http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28568 for a later Rx SDK. Linked from the Rx download page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610

Comment: Download no longer on microsoft.com :(

Answer (score 3):

System.Threading, the assembly for the TPL used to be included in the Rx releases, but no longer is.

You may be able to find it in older versions.

That said, an `IObservable<T>` is analogous to a `Task<T>` with the key distinction that a `Task<T>` can have only 1 result, an `IObservable<T>` is a stream of 0 or more results.

Answer (score 1):

Rx in .NET 3.5 can't use Tasks, it uses the .NET 3.5 Thread Pool - however, as Scott says, IObservable works like Task when the IObservable is one item long.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if i am wrong any where.

Observables and observers are mainly related to task - Observe (Wait for data) & Subscribe (for Observers to get data which is pushed).

Observable provides two operators to improve performance of the above two task.

1). Observable.ObserveOn - Asynchronously notify observer on specified schedular.
The task can be performed in better way using Schedular where it takes argument of either

- Scheduler.CurrentThread (Observe on current running thread)
- Scheduler.NewThread (Observe everytime on new thread)
- Scheduler.TaskPool (Observe using TaskPool mechanism, i think you might be interested.)
- Scheduler.ThreadPool (Observe using ThreadPool mechanism)

same goes for the second....

2). Observable.SubscribeOn - Asynchronously subscribe - unsubscribe observers on specified schedulers.

It also has same options as above to schedule the subscription.

Thus Rx provides inbuilt capabilities to schedule your process to give fast results.