# Correct placement of lock object in thread managing class

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to create a `ThreadManager` object that handles threads created during the application.

The whole purpose is to terminate the threads before closing the main `Form` and not allowing the creation of new ones during that closing time. As you can see I apply the locking around the whole thread creation code and also inside `AllowNewThreads`.

I'm pretty sure that there will be times that 2 or more new threads will wait on the lock, which is not something **VERY** bad, but could cause small delays. Could there be another alternative of the locking placement in order to have better results or perhaps another strategy I have not yet considered?

```
public class ThreadManager
{
    #region Fields
    private List<Thread> _threads;
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static object _lock;
    private bool _allowNewThreads;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public bool AllowNewThreads
    {
        get
        {
            return _allowNewThreads;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _allowNewThreads = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public int CountAlive
    {
        get
        {
            int count = (from t in _threads where (t.IsAlive) select t).Count();
            return count;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    private ThreadManager()
    {
        _threads = new List<Thread>();
    }

    public static ThreadManager Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton<ThreadManager>.Instance; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    // There must always be thread body in order to create a new thread.
    // Thread parameters are the objects that are needed for calculations etc inside the thread and are optional
    // Start info is the thread itself parameters needed for its creation, such as the thread name, the apartment state 
    // and if it's background or not. That information is optional as well.
    public bool TryAddThread(ParameterizedThreadStart threadBody, object threadParams, ThreadStartInfo startInfo)
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!AllowNewThreads)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Creation of new threads is denied.");
                }

                Thread f = new Thread(threadBody);

                if (startInfo != null)
                {
                    f.Name = startInfo.Name;
                    f.SetApartmentState(startInfo.ApartmentState);
                    f.IsBackground = startInfo.IsBackground;
                }

                if (threadParams != null)
                {
                    f.Start(threadParams);
                }
                else
                {
                    f.Start();
                }

                _threads.Add(f);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("AddThread", ex);
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: 'I'm trying to create a ThreadManager object that handles threads created during the application'.  Can you find some other way of doing whatever it is you want? Queues/threadPools/anything that does not involve direct thread micro-management - a recipie for pain, trouble, difficult debugging and hassle that should be avoided unless your boss/customer is holding a gun to your head, (even then, I think I would rather be shot :).  Do you absolutely need to terminate those threads, (eg. because they hold DB connections/transactions that must be closed/committed)?

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes. The threads are holding DB connections and transactions and they have to be terminated. Also some other threads are holding open connections with websites. The main problem of the application at the moment is the thread termination sequence that causes occasionally Access Violation exceptions, unhandled by .NET 3.5 Framework. And no, cannot use 4.0 unfortunately.

Comment: You should have a **static** lock. And I am just interested how will you terminate threads, surely not by calling `Abort()`?

Comment: The threads are terminated themselves. `Abort()` is prohibited!

Comment: @oleksii Why would he want a static lock on non-static class (even if it is a singleton)?

Comment: Just a question: why is there a try/catch? Just because of your exception? knowing the cost of a throw, you may prefer an if/else bloc.

Comment: There can be thrown exceptions, why not catch them? What if/else block do you mean?

Comment: I don't mean not to catch exception. I mean : not throw an exception to catch it in the same function. could be : if (!AllowNewThreads) { _logger.ErrorE("foo"); success = false; return; }

Comment: I'll consider your proposal, it's something that I might change. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair **static** would ensure there is only 1 object to lock. Otherwise the code can be misused by other developers, who accidentally did not call an `Instance` singleton property but instead used a `new ThreadManager()`. You may end up in the situation where one thread locking one object, and another thread locking another objects and both boys perform work at the same time. The catch is, there must be only one object on which both threads would try to acquire a lock.

Comment: I have a private Constructor in `ThreadManager`, so no `new ThreadManager(`) can be created.

Comment: Well, that's complicated, we are lacking info: when is AllowNewThread modified? When are threads removed from the list? I think you _lock should be marked as volatile and the Count should be locked (otherwise, if you remove a thread from the list while counting you may have an exception). Appart from that, your code looks Ok to me. you may try and reduce the time within the lock by starting your thread outside... but you won't be earning much

Comment: The threads are never removed from the list. `AllowNewThread` is modified when `FormClosing` event of the main form is raised in order to stop the creation of new threads. The rest of the (running) threads are supposed to close one after another, so I just have to wait until `CountAlive` returns 0 to continue with the application termination.

Comment: Seems fine then. you have a memory leak, but you may don't care, depending on the use case... I couldn't do better (except the volatile)

Comment: What is the memory leak?

Comment: @oleksii Normally I would agree with you.  But the design pattern/usage of his class seems to enforce it.  Even if he did allow new instances of `ThreadManager`, it seems to me that each instance will manage its own collection of threads independently; I see no reason for them to be sharing locks between each other when they do not share state.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments, you are going just to wait until threads are done with the job. Therefore instead of manual managing of threads you can use `ThreadPool`, because it is much more efficient for short-lived jobs. For long running tasks I would use a `Task` class (which supports cancellations!) that is available for .NET 3.5 (I think Rx supports it, maybe there is even simpler way).

Threads are really heavy objects and their management can become a tricky part of your app.

---

Also a comment on the locking object (before the edit), you should try to make sure there is only one object per class in the whole application on which threads can lock, otherwise you will get nasty bugs.

Comment: `Task` is supported in .NET 4 and 4.5. `ThreadPool` in my opinion is not suited for my application. Each thread manipulates different data. I don't have let's say a matrix to make calculations. I just parse some data from a website and store that data to a database. There's also a keep alive thread. Most of them live during the whole app lifetime, but when closing it I have to wait for the timeouts to expire and also commit any transactions.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891787/threading-tasks-analog-in-rx-extensions-in-net-3-5) is a discussion of Task<T> and options for .NET 3.5