# How to stop the execution of a method after a specific time?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I need to stop the execution of a method if it has not completed within a limited period of time.

To do this work I can use the `Thread.Abort` method in this way:

```
void RunWithTimeout(ThreadStart entryPoint, int timeout)
{
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            entryPoint();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {   }

    }) { IsBackground = true };

    thread.Start();

    if (!thread.Join(timeout))
        thread.Abort();
}
```

Given that I'm using .NET 3.5, is there a better way?

Edit: following the comments here my `entryPoint`, but I'm looking for a good way for any `entryPoint`.

```
void entryPoint()
{
   // I can't use ReceiveTimeout property
   // there is not a ReceiveTimeout for the Compact Framework
   socket.Receive(...);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to throw a ThnreadAbortException without using Thread.Abort, or do you want to stop the execution of a method after a timeout?

Comment: @dtb the second: stop the execution of a method after a timeout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-sharp-generic-timeout

Comment: Consider using a Task from the Task Parallel Library with a CancellationToken.

Comment: @AndreiSchneider The answer is worse than my solution...

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan I can't use task, edit my question (.NET framework 3.5)

Comment: Why don't use the Async version?

Comment: @avip how to completely stop the async version after the timeout?

Comment: I think Close()/Dispose() are best bet - but in that case you might as well do it with the synchronous method. Anyhow I need to test it.

Comment: Avoiding Thread.Abort is always a good idea.   
Avoiding it on a thread you did not create is even better. 

How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil)   
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Dangers of Thread.Abort by Eric Lippert  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer depends on 'the work'. If work is something that can be safely stopped (i.e. not some I/O blocking operation) - use `Backgroundworker.CancelAsync(...)`

If you do have to cut hard - I'd consider using a `Process`, in which case the `Aborting` process is cleaner - and `process.WaitForExit(timeout)` is your friend.

Suggested TPL is great but unfortunately does not exist in .Net 3.5.

EDIT: You can use [Reactive Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project) to follow Jan de Vaan's suggestion.

Here is my 'action timeout' snip - it's mainly here for others to comment on:

```
    public static bool WaitforExit(this Action act, int timeout)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(act, cts.Token);
        if (Task.WaitAny(new[] { task }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout)) < 0)
        { // timeout
            cts.Cancel();
            return false;
        }
        else if (task.Exception != null)
        { // exception
            cts.Cancel();
            throw task.Exception;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**EDIT**: Apparently this isn't exactly what OP wanted. Here's my attempt to devise a 'cancelable' socket receiver:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static object RunWithTimeout<T>(Func<T,object> act, int timeout, T obj) where T : IDisposable
    {
        object result = null;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => { 
            try { result = act(obj); }
            catch {}    // this is where we end after timeout...
        });

        thread.Start();
        if (!thread.Join(timeout))
        {
            obj.Dispose();
            thread.Join();
        }
        return result;
    }       
}

class Test
{
    public void SocketTimeout(int timeout)
    {
        using (var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
        {
            Object res = Ext.RunWithTimeout(EntryPoint, timeout, sock);
        }
    }

    private object EntryPoint(Socket sock)
    {
        var buf = new byte[256];
        sock.Receive(buf);
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Comment: CancelAsync doesn't actually abort your thread or anything like that. It sends a message to the worker thread that work should be cancelled via BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending. Your DoWork delegate that is being ran in the background must periodically check this property and handle the cancellation itself. So, it's not what I neeed. The second option (create a process) is a cleaner solution, but requires many additional resources. Reactive Extension is fine for hobby project, but I need a solution for a commercial project (I can't update to .NET 4.0). Anyway +1, it's a good answer :)

Comment: Yap. Can we see the actual 'DoWork' ?

Comment: See edit, but (as I wrote) i prefer a good way for any entryPoint.

Comment: Avoiding Thread.Abort is always a good idea.   
Avoiding it on a thread you did not create is even better. 

How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil)   
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Dangers of Thread.Abort by Eric Lippert  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Thread.Abort is usually a bad solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort). You should use a flag indicating if the operation is canceled and check it inside your entryPoint function.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunWithTimeout((token) =>
                               {
                                   Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                   if (token.Cancel)
                                   {
                                       Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
                                   }
                               }, 1000);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private class Token
        {
            public bool Cancel { get; set; }
        }

        static void RunWithTimeout(Action<Token> entryPoint, int timeout)
        {

            Token token = new Token();

            var thread = new Thread(() => entryPoint(token)) { IsBackground = true };

            thread.Start();

            if (!thread.Join(timeout))
                token.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't check the value of token.Cancel everywhere. If I need to stop after 1 second I have to stop after 1 second, no matter where I am.

Comment: Another solution is to use a child process... but it's more resource-consuming.