# Timer to limit its loading time for try{} catch{} in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>

<script language="c#" runat="server">

void BtnCheck_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e) {
try
{
    IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org");
    LblValue.Text += "<br>" + Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org#";
    foreach(IPAddress ip in GetIPHost.AddressList)
    {
        long HostIpaddress = ip.Address;
        LblValue.Text += ip.ToString() + "#";
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    LblValue.Text += "<br>" + Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org#";
    LblValue.Text += "" + ex.Message + "#";
}

}
</script>

<html>
<title>DNS LOOKUP</title>
<head>
</head>
<body OnLoad="BtnCheck_Click" value="Send" runat="server">
<asp:Label id="LblValue" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to make a dns lookup, it can take more than 3-4 seconds to get the information. I want to limit its loading time to 1000 milliseconds. If it passes to 1001 milliseconds or more, I want to exit the `try` block. How can I insert a timer to this code?

Comment: Do you want it to execute the `catch` block if it exits the `try` block with the timeout?

Comment: it is not necessary the catch block's response. i only want to get the information with **GetHostByName()** in 1000 milliseconds, if it cant turn any information then a NULL result is okay

Answer (score 1):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions for this. Just NuGet "Rx-Main". Then you can do this:

```
string hostName = Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org";

IObservable<string> getIPAddresses =
    from host in Observable.Start(() => Dns.GetHostByName(hostName))
    select String.Join("#", host.AddressList.Select(ip => ip.Address.ToString()));

IObservable<string> getTimeout =
    from x in Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1001))
    select ""; // Or Timeout message here

string text = Observable.Amb(getIPAddresses, getTimeout).Wait();

LblValue.Text += "<br>" + hostName + "#";
LblValue.Text += text;
```

The key to making this work is the `Observable.Amb` operator which basically tries to run both observables and the first one to produce a value wins. The `Wait()` then simply turns the `IObservable<string>` into a `string` based on the last value produced by the observable and since the observables only produce a single value that's all you get.

Comment: As i said it is my first try with asp.net, sorry if i cant understand your answer, i also copy and paste these codes to my codes above, i got this error; *CS0103: 'Observable' name not valid inside the content* something like that a translation from my language to english THANKS

Comment: @G.KISA - Did you NuGet "Rx-Main"? Once you do that you'll need to add the right namespaces but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WaitForExit` extension method [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279939/4270650) to do this.

Simply wrap your `Dns.GetHostByName` call into an `Action` which will assign the result to the `GetIPHost` variable, and invoke the extension method.

```
try
{
    IPHostEntry GetIPHost = null;
    var action = new Action(() => GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org"));
    action.WaitForExit(1000); // this will cancel the method after 1000 milliseconds
    if (GetIPHost != null)
    {
        LblValue.Text += "<br>" + Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org#";
        foreach (IPAddress ip in GetIPHost.AddressList)
        {
            long HostIpaddress = ip.Address;
            LblValue.Text += ip.ToString() + "#";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LblValue.Text += "<br>" + Request.QueryString["domain"] + ".org#";
    LblValue.Text += "" + ex.Message + "#";
}
```

The `WaitForExit` extension method:

```
public static class ActionExtentions
{
    public static bool WaitForExit(this Action action, int timeout)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, cts.Token);
        if (Task.WaitAny(new[] { task }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout)) < 0)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            return false;
        }
        else if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            throw task.Exception;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i eddited my question, wrote all the codes in my .aspx page This is my first try with asp.net, i copy your codes and paste them inside my script tags and get en error on the line *public static bool WaitForExit(this Action action, int timeout)*

Comment: What's the error? You must declare extension methods inside a public static class, so be sure to include the `public static class ActionExtentions` as well.