# DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback in another class

Tags: c#, callback

I have two classes, below is a break down on what's going on before I go on to ask my question...

**myClass1:**

```
myClass1(){

    myClass2 c2 = new myClass2();
    c2.service();

}

public void myFunction1(){

    Console.Write("Function returned!");

}
```

**myClass2:**

```
public void service(){

    callWebService(myFunction1); // The parameter you pass here is the function that control 
                      // will pass back to once the called function is done.

}

public void callWebService(DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback){

    //Calls web service and does some other operations

}
```

And finaly the question. As you can see above I have the 2 classes, class1 calls a function in class2. That function calls another function also in class2 that calls a webservice. Once that web serivce is done control flow passes back to whatever function you passes in the function call.

But that means you're stuck to one class since the callback function should be in the same class. So the question is, how can I pass a function in another class to be the callback function?

Hope all this makes sense, please don't hesitate asking anything to clear things up a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `Service` class and pass `MyClass1's` method to it.For e.g In the below code , the function  `ServiceCallComplete` is passed as a parameter to the `Service` class constructor.

The function can be saved as either [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) or [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) delegate type(depending on your callback function definition).Once the service job is done ,calling the delegate(`_callBack()`) will invoke the callback function on `MyClass1`.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    //The callback Function
    public void ServiceCallComplete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Function returned.");
    }

}

public class Service
{
    //delegate to store the callback function.
    private readonly Action _callBack;

    public Service(Action callBack)
    {
        //store the callback function
        _callBack = callBack;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        //long running operation
        .
        .
       //Invoke the callback
        _callBack();
    }
}


MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1();
Service svc = new Service(obj.ServiceCallComplete);
svc.Method();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a delegate, use an event:

```
class MyClass1
{
    public MyClass1()
    {
        var c2 = new MyClass2();

        c2.ActionwebServiceCalled += MyCallBack; //register for the event
        c2.CallWebService();
    }

    public void MyCallBack(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Function returned!");
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public event DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler ActionwebServiceCalled;

    public void CallWebService()
    {
        DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e = null;

        //Calls web service and does some other operations...

        var handler = ActionwebServiceCalled;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Having said that, you'd might want to introduce asynchrony to the web service call, in which case the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) is the way to go, provided that you have .NET 4 ([or Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project)). For .NET 3.5 and lower, you'll want to follow the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx).