# Wait for all nested asynchronous operations to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, async-await

I have `BeginInvoke` a delegate which `internally invokes multiple asynchronous operations` and i want to wait for all internal operations to complete `before callback for main asynchronous operation executes.`

I could have easily achieved that using `async, await or TPL` but can't since my target platform is `.Net3.5`. Sample code demonstrating my problem -

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> abc = new List<string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Action(() =>
            {
                A();
            }).BeginInvoke(MainCallback, null);
    }

    static void MainCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        foreach (string str in abc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Main Callback {0}",str));
        }
    }

    static void A()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            new Action(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }).BeginInvoke(Callback, i);
        }
    }

    static void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        abc.Add(result.AsyncState.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want the output to be something like this -

```
Main Callback 0
Main Callback 1
Main Callback 2
Main Callback 3
Main Callback 4
Main Callback 5
Main Callback 6
Main Callback 7
Main Callback 8
Main Callback 9
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2987439/34397

Comment: @SLaks - Will look that. But can you please let me know if it's possible without TPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to track how many operations you've started.

Then, in each callback, decrement this counter (to indicate that one of the operations is finished).

When it reaches `0`, everything is finished, so you can call the final callback.

This is how `Task.WhenAll()` works.

Since this is a multi-threaded environment, you must use `Interlocked.Decrement` (carefully).

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned `carefully`. Is this good enough - `Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
            abc.Add(result.AsyncState.ToString());
            if (counter == 0)
                MainCallback(null);` or i need to do something more?

Comment: @RohitVats: No; `counter` may change between those two lines.  You need to check the return value of `Decrement()`.

Comment: `counter = Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);` - is this what you meant? And do i need to wrap entire code in `lock`?

Comment: @RohitVats: No; that's even worse.  If a different thread decrements it at the same time, its changes will be swallowed.  YOu need to check whether the return value is `0`.

Comment: You can use `Interlocked` to write lock-free thread-safe code.  However, you need to learn more about thread-safety.  See also my blog post, http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures

Comment: Thanks i will read on that for sure. Will this suffice - `if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter) == 0)
                    MainCallback(null);`?

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve expected output by modifying little of your code.
Modify your `A` method as below. You're done

```
static void A()
{
    List<IAsyncResult> results = new List<IAsyncResult>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        results.Add(new Action(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }).BeginInvoke(Callback, i));
    }

    foreach (var res in results)
    {
        res.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Does this helps?

Comment: I think he wants to wait **asynchronously**.

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean by `wait asynchronously`? as you can see Here ThreadPool Thread only waits for operations to complete not the main Thread. OP stated that `i want to wait for all internal operations to complete before callback for main asynchronous operation executes` This code does what he wants. If am wrong correct me!

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is blocking.  He just wants to call the callback later.

Comment: -1 for sleeping in a multithreaded asynchronous environment. This answer is not useful.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I assume he's referring to `WaitOne()`, which sleeps.

Comment: @djechlin Stop **blindly** downvoting! That was the method included in question.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion but SLaks answer is what i want. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The point is that it's a blocking call, which defeats the purpose of asynchrony.

Comment: @SLaks Agree with you completely