# How I can call an asynchronous method that receives parameters in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, asynchronous

I have a method that receives a parameter and i want to call asynchronously when a click method is called.

```
    Private Sub audioBox(ByVal message As String)
        cls_utilidades.Audio_Box(" String ")
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)_
    Handles Button1.Click
        'call the method
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  You could use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), start a plain [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), use the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc.  Here is an example using the threadpool.

You have to rewrite your method to match the [`WaitCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) signature (which takes a plain `Object`):

```
'be sure to add
Imports System.Threading.ThreadPool

'...    

'need an object type to pass
Private Class AudioBoxArgs
    Public Message As String
End Class

Private Sub audioBox(ByVal state As Object)
   cls_utilidades.Audio_Box(DirectCast(state, AudioBoxArgs).Message)
End Sub
```

then in your click handler :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                                            Handles Button1.Click
   Dim someMessage As New AudioBoxArgs()
   someMessage.Message = "someMessage"
   QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf audioBox, someMessage)
End Sub
```

As with all asynchronous code, you should make sure that `cls_utilidades.Audio_Box()` is a safe method to call from a separate thread.  If you're not yet familiar with thread safety it's something you will have to start learning.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to do it using TPL (Task Parallel Library, .NET 4.0+):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                                           Handles Button1.Click
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf audioBox, "message")
  'or
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() audioBox("message"))
End Sub
```

This can get more complicated than it seems, because you should also handle exceptions, cancellation etc., same with any multi-threaded approach.

If you are up for that, look into TPL, good framework - lots to learn there.

Comment: OP tagged with VS2008 (which supports up to .NET 3.5), so this is not applicable.  There are the reactive extensions, but they do not support the whole TPL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Comment: @J...: Oops, did not notice that. That's why you did not mention it. :) I will leave it here anyway, maybe OP will consider upgrading.

Comment: [Can I use the task parallel library in a .Net 3.5 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project)

Comment: Async and TPL are big reasons, to be sure!

Comment: @J...: Yeah, `async` is another big deal, but I keep thinking in terms of .NET 4.0, just cause many customers are still using XP and Windows 2003, where 4.5 simply does not work.